# ASP.Net MVC - Ajax.BeginRequest() not generating an ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my Test.cshtml:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test", new AjaxOptions()))
{
    <p>
        Some String: <input name="someString" type="text" /> 
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Where jquery-1.4.4.min.js is included by the layout.

My Controller has the following two actions:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string someString)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json("Okey-dokey");
    return View();
}
```

It seems that when I hit submit, it always does a full post-back, Request.IsAjaxRequest() is never true!

What gives?

Comment: are you including the script jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your layout page?

Comment: @counsellorben Ahh, that would be the issue. Post as an answer and I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George,

Please make sure that you include the script jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your layout page.

counsellorben

Answer (score 1):

I see no ajax functionality in your code examples.

Comment: Isn't that what Ajax.Begin() form is supposed to do? I thought it was supposed to hijack the form submission process if javascript is enabled. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: You're right, I did, it was a typo, Ajax.BeginForm still behaves the same. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Something like this to get ajax functionality

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "ControllerName" ,null,
       new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "FunctionToCallOnSuccess" }))
```

Comment: Sorry, I had mistyped, I AM using Ajax.BeginForm() - it is still being processed as a full postback request

Answer (score 0):

It is post, indeed.
You should use AJAX call, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#myButton" ).click(function(){
        $.getJSON("/Controller/Test", {someString: $("#someString").val()}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and in your form:

```
<p>
    Some String: <input name="someString" id="someString" type="text" /> 
</p>
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

This should work.

Comment: I agree that this would work, but this is beside the point of using the unobtrusive javascript stuff provided by Ajax.BeginForm. Also note that using a GET for something like this might expose a JSON Hijacking security vulnerability if you plan on returning any secure data.

Comment: And I agree with you. Sorry for that.